# Flex Seal Opinion?

Tags: waterproofing

I'm just wondering what is the opinion on Flex Seal for general waterproofing. What can and can't it do, is it worth it, is it a miracle fix-all as it shows? Basically, is it worth using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I treat it as a somewhat temporary solution.  I have found that it does expand well and initially holds its seal - really well.  However the big flaw I have found is when just doing one coat, no matter how thick, there it is going to crack if I put it in an area with huge temp shifts or sunlight.

I have found that for a leaky sink or faucet or small interior things it is a good stop gap.  For these things I don't really know how long it would last but I would say at least 2 months but for the most part I get new stuff within a month or two.

So in conclusion I would recommend keeping a can handy... but I would never want to see someone working on my home using it.